# Google sheet sumif returns 0

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, sum, sumifs

I am trying to use sumif function but it alwasy returns me 0, at the beggining I was using `,` instead `;` for europe, changed that but it keeps giving me 0

[image]

Comment: `=SUMIF(I1:I4; "a"; H1:H4)`

Comment: yeee the other way ournd, first I then H , but in all documentation is how i wrote

Comment: when reading documentation, note the difference between SUMIF() and SUMIFS() @kosnkov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=SUMIF(I1:I4; "a"; H1:H4)
```

[image]

or:

```
=SUMIFS(H1:H4; I1:I4; "a")
```

[image]

or:

```
=SUM(FILTER(H1:H4; I1:I4="a"))
```